# Kibana - Datatable count aggregation filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm working on a visualization on Kibana in order to count the amount of request with the `STATE:"ERROR"` filter.
My final goal is to display the percentage of ERROR for my requests.

Here is a display of my current visualisation :

[image]

Folliwing [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) documentation, I tried to create the following JSON custom filter Input :

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "messages" : {
      "filters" : {
        "filters" : [
          { "match" : { "STATE" : "ERROR"   }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
Did someone already create some custom count operation or even percentage on the DataTable visualization ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON input section is not the right location for what you want to do.

You need to go in the Buckets section below the Metrics one and create a `filters` aggregation.

[image]